# Firefox Quantum online bookmark manager

Tags: android, web-browser, cross-platform, bookmark

since FF Quantum many old plugins does not works anymore so I'm looking for some tool to comfortably manage web browser bookmarks, here are my requirements:

Must have features:

- support for (sub)groups (or labels, tags, directories) to which
  bookmarks can be organized
- saving all actually opened tabs (e.g. to group named
  YY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS)
- loading/opening all bookmarks from given group
- storing bookmarks in online cloud
- exporting from cloud to plain text (csv, xml)
- Synchronization between: Windows, Linux, Android
  easy manipulation: moving one or multiple bookmarks from one group to another (drag & drop)

Optional features:

- cross browser compatibility
- finding duplicates or announcing when duplicate bookmark is going to be added
- ability to rate bookmark (e.g. like grades in school)
- ability to add notes to bookmark or groups
- easy filtering: search by date, notes, rate, key words

PS: please note that if your favorite bookmark manager does not contain some requirement mention it in answer. I have some technical background so e.g. importing/exporting can be done via some scripting and I can maybe use some workarounds etc.

PPS: I'm wiling to switch to e.g. to Chrome if it is necessary.